# Checkout the commit corresponding to a branch

Tags: git, git-checkout

I'm using `git worktree`, and want to check out a branch which is also checked out on a different workdir. I don't need the branch itself, but I need the commit corresponding to the branch as a detached HEAD. `git checkout $(git rev-parse mybranch)` is one solution, but it's verbose (and I'd prefer to not add an alias for it if a simple way exists already). Is there any way to succinctly check out the commit corresponding to a branch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per `git help checkout`, the direct and un-magical solution is:

```
git checkout --detach mybranch
```

Answer (score 1):

`git checkout mybranch^0` or `git checkout mybranch~0` both work.

`~0` means "The 0th ancestor", which is the commit itself. `^0` means "the 0th parent" for commits with multiple parents (merge commits). I'm not sure why this resolves to the commit itself, but it does.

Since `git checkout <anything that is not just the name of a branch>` will check out the commit as a detached HEAD, `git checkout mybranch~0` will work even though `git checkout mybranch` does not.